# Linking two AWS Data Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have two AWS Data Pipelines A,B. I would like to make B depend on A: after A finishes running, I would like to run B. Is there an easy way of linking the two? I presume there should be a dirty way of making this work by having A output a "done" file and then having B read that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can implement a lambda invocation stage as the final stage in
  Pipeline A.
- Use the CLI `aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution` equivalent in
  Python/Java/NodeJS SDK in the lambda function to execute your Pipeline B.

Should be pretty straight forward.